# Visualising a single transverse wave

Tags: waves

I am revisiting a picture of Young's double split experiment involving light and I'm afraid that I've had a blank:

[image]

Do the red lines on the LHS of the barrier represent a single wave, or lots of individual waves that are coherent?

In other words, does a single wave of light look like a rippled sheet or a rippled string in 3D?

Comment: A couple of issues come up right away. What is a "single wave" in the first place? That figure is meant to represent a *plane wave*. Secondly, what do you mean by "look like"? There is no phyical movement involved as in a sheet or a stinrg, right? The amplitude is not displacement but the strength of electric and magnetic fields.

Comment: Of possible intrest concerning the RHS of the slitted screen: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506937/wavefunction-of-an-electron-after-a-slit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light is usually represented as a sine wave but that is misleading. An electromagnetic wave is not a displacement of anything. Nothing is actually *moving* back and forth. What oscillates is the strength or the direction of the electric field at every point. So no, light not similar to a rippled sheet or string.

What those red lines represent are regions where the electric field is a maximum (or any other point in it's cycle). To the left of the diagram, light arrives as a plane wave so the regions with a common value of the electric field are parallel planes. After a barrier, regions with a common value for the electric are curved.

Answer (score 0):

The monochromatic light on the left side of your sketch is shown with its wave crests and wave troughs. The sketch is not animated, but if it were, the red lines would move towards the double slit.

The same should be with the left side., the red lines are expanding circles. It’s strange, how Young could  conclude from water waves, where constructive and destructive interferences lead to nonstationary intensities at a cross-section (the observation screen) about light waves from fringes. Imagine expanding circles and you’ll see that the fringes on the screen are moving.

Furthermore in our days it is clear that the concept of destructive interference for light doesn’t work. Simply the light gets deflected and is concentrated in some areas more and in some areas less (see a lot of explanations on PSE about this point).  Let us combine this insight with the phenomenon that even behind single edges fringes occur and that even for single photon experiments after some time statistically the fringes occur. Maybe interference of single photons with itself is something what is describable. But the deflection of single photons on single edges Has to do more with the edge-photon-interaction as with interferences.

The constituents of light, the photons  are particles (indivisible units) and the are wavelike with their  oscillating electric and magnetic field components. Should is be unimaginable, that these oscillations inducing an interaction with the surface electrons at the edges? As a result a photon interaction induces a static field on the edges which lead to the fringes?